# Using Javascript how to add days and years to the current date?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the current date and add `1` day to it. Secondly I need to get the current date and add `1` year to it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you searched for anything?

Comment: @kriggs yes I got the day but not the year

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? if so please post your code !

Comment: _I got the day but not the year_ ... same process, different `methods`

Comment: A simple [Google search brings up this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee532932%28v=vs.94%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, create a new date, get the day and the year increase them and return a new date with the new values.

This is a DEMO returning a date increased with one day and one year from the current one.

```js
var date = new Date();
document.write(date);
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDate();
var year = date.getFullYear();

var newDate = new Date(month+"-"+(day+1)+"-"+(year+1));

document.write("<h3>"+newDate+"</h3>");
```